# Loose version in requirements.in

Tags: pip, requirements.txt, pip-tools

I am writing a library A that is used by an application B,

I am using `pip-compile` in the process for both library A and application B, and would like my `requirements.txt` to have a loose dependency such as

```
# requirements.in for library A
pandas~=1.4.0  # will install the highest version available above 1.4.0 , but not 1.5.0  or higher.
```

After `pip-compile`, this is what I have

```
# requirements.txt for library A
...
pandas==1.4.4
...
```

Is it possible to have this instead, for the output of `pip-compile`, so that other application B can decide, during dependency resolution, on what exact version of `pandas==1.4.x` to use?

```
# requirements.txt for library A
...
pandas~=1.4.0
...
```

```
# requirements.in for application B
libraryA==1.1.1
pandas==1.4.2

# There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies:
#   pandas==1.4.2 from ...
#   pandas==1.4.4 (from libraryA==1.1.1->-r requirements.in (line 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not how `pip-compile` works, but that you are using it at all for a library.
Your library is not supposed to pin versions. The version pinning is made at the application side, just because libraries don't pin packages. And for a good reason: libraries don't have the context of all your dependencies and cannot decide for you which version of package `x` is compatible with all your dependencies requiring it. What I would expect from your library is to have a pyproject.toml/setup.cfg/setup.py file instructing pip like this:

```
#pyproject.toml
[project]
dependencies = [
    "pandas~=1.4.0"
]
```

And then, when I pin my versions in my application with pip-tools, pip will decide which is the most up-to-date appropriate version of pandas for my specific project and dependency tree.

Your library should give the range of your dependencies' versions you expect it to work well with, but should never pin a version, except the extremely rare case where you depend on something really specific in one and only one version of your dependency [a bug most probably :)].

Answer (score -4):

This should be possible by using the string version

```
pip install 'pandas>=1.4.0,<1.5.0'
```

Use double quotes for Windows.

Comment: It would work, but the question is about `pip-compile` specifically.

Comment: My bad, I read it the wrong way. With `pip-compile` you can specify just the upper version inside your `requirements.in`: just write `pandas<1.5.0`.
If you need a minimum version, you can use the same syntax `pandas>=1.4.0,<1.5.0`

Comment: my problem is that is compiles to exact maximum version found

Comment: I don't think is possible to install multiple versions, pip will override the current installed for another one. pip-compile is still dependent on the pip logic anyway.
You should manually find the version which will support the same dependencies versions